# Применение switch к TextWatcher

Tags: android, activity, android-switch

У меня есть EditText, и туда вводится слово.
Если туда введётся одно слово, то откроется один Activity,
если введётся другое слово, то откроется другое Activity.
Это всё будет реализовано с помощью TextWatcher, но я не знаю, как туда поместить switch. 
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: `onTextChanged`- то что вам нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как можно использовать `switch` в указанной вами функции? мне просто уже и самому интересно, ТС задал довольно нестандартный вопрос)) вот если через `if` делать, то я представляю как, но вот через `switch` хоть убей не могу придумать. Весь вечер уже сижу)

Comment: Ну... просто `public void onTextChanged(s:Editable) { switch(s.toString()) {case "example" : println("example") break;} }`

Comment: Блин, не подумал)))) буду знать))) надеюсь ТС это поможет решить его проблему)